# Compute distance metric in a complete graph

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

Suppose I have an array, namely `Map`. `Map[i][j]` means the distance between area `i` and area `j`. Under this definition, we get:

a) `Map[i][i]` always equals 0.

b) `Map[i][k] <= Map[i][j] + Map[j][k]` for all `i,j,k`

I want to build a function `func(Map,k)` returning a metric `D`, while `D[i][j]` is the shortest distance of a route from area `i` to area `j`, and this route should pass through at least `k` different area.

This is my python code to do so:

```
def func(Map,k):
    n=len(Map)    
    D_temp = [list(x) for x in Map]
    D = [list(x) for x in Map]
    for m in range(k - 1):    
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                tmp = [D[i][x] + Map[x][j] for x in range(n) if x != i and x != j]
                D_temp[i][j] = min(tmp)
        D = [list(x) for x in D_temp]
    return D
func([[0, 2, 3], [2, 0, 1], [3, 1, 0]],2)
```

return a distance metric `D` which equals `[[4, 4, 3], [4, 2, 5], [3, 5, 2]]`

`D[0][0]` equals `4`, because the shortest route from `area0` to `area0` which pass through at least 2 area is {`area0`-->`area1`-->`area0`}, and the distance of the route is `Map[0][1]`+`Map[1][0]`=2+2=4

Wanted to know what would be the best way to do that?

Comment: dont name things after built-ins. There is already something called `map()` if you specify `map = [1,2,3]` you shadow it - because now `map` points to a list and no longer to the `map()` function.

Comment: I guess you could just do Dijkstra's, just do not stop before the tour has length `k`. Also: Is it true that `map[i][k] <= map[i][j] + map[j][k]` for all `i,j,k`? (In other words: Is the direct path always the shortest? In this case, you could also use A*)

Comment: are all areas interconnected? if so you might get `0 ->1 (1 is lowest dist) ->0 ->1 ->0 ->1->0 for k == 5 and 0->0` you might want to specify some more rules like: back-forth, circles (0->1->2->0->1 for 0->1 and k=3) etc  ...

Comment: @tobias_k  Yes, `Map[i][k] <= Map[i][j] + Map[j][k]` for all `i,j,k`

Comment: @PatrickArtner route {0 ->1 (1 is lowest dist) ->0 ->1 ->0 ->1->0}  is not valid for `k =5` because only different area is counted. route {0 ->1 ->0 ->1 ->0 ->1->0} only pass through 2 different area.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the A* algorithm for this, using `Map[i][j]` as the heuristic for the minimum remaining distance to the target node (assuming that, as you said, `Map[i][j] <= Map[i][x] + Map[x][j]` for all `i,j,x`). The only difference to a regular A* would be that you only accept paths if they have a minimum length of `k`.

```
import heapq
def min_path(Map, k, i, j):
    heap = [(0, 0, i, [])]
    while heap:
        _, cost, cur, path = heapq.heappop(heap)
        if cur == j and len(path) >= k:
            return cost
        for other in range(len(Map)):
            if other != cur:
                c = cost + Map[cur][other]
                heapq.heappush(heap, (c + Map[other][j], c, other, path + [other]))
```

Change your `func` to return a list comprehension using this `min_path` accordingly.

```
def func(Map, k):
    n = len(Map)  
    return [[min_path(Map, k, i, j) for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
res = func([[0, 2, 3], [2, 0, 1], [3, 1, 0]], 2)
```

This gives me the result `[[4, 4, 3], [4, 2, 3], [3, 3, 2]]` for `len(path) >= k`, or `[[4, 4, 3], [4, 2, 5], [3, 5, 2]]` for `len(path) == k`.